# How to get all parents node data when clicked/expanded in jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

How to get all parents **node** data in `jstree`  when i click a child node

suppose i have a `jstree` like below:

[image]

**Observe:**  when i select `File 2` i should get all parent node data i,e  **Root node 2 ---> Child 2 ---> File 2**

```js
$('#using_json_2').jstree({ 'core' : {
    'data' : [
       { "id" : "ajson1", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Simple root node", "date":"2018"},
       { "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root node 2", "date":"2018"},
       { "id" : "ajson3", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 1", "date":"12" },
       { "id" : "ajson4", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 2", "date":"12" },
         { "id" : "ajson5", "parent" : "ajson4", "text" : "File 1", "date":"12","children": false,"icon":"fa fa-file-o"  },
                { "id" : "ajson6", "parent" : "ajson4", "text" : "File 2", "date":"12","children": false,"icon":"fa fa-file-o"  }
    ]
} });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>


<div id="using_json_2"></div>
```

**Expected Output:** (When i select node `File 2`)

```
var allParentsNode = [
{ "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root node 2"},
{ "id" : "ajson4", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 2" },
{ "id" : "ajson6", "parent" : "ajson4", "text" : "File 2", "children": false,"icon":"fa fa-file-o"  }]
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not a parent node

Comment: @blex, But  **"Root node 2"** is parent node for the above `File 2`

Comment: @blex, Edited my Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [docs](https://www.jstree.com/api/), you can see there is a `changed.jstree` event fired when you select a node. And you can use the `get_selected` and `get_path` methods to do what you want:

```js
// Make it a variable so you can access it later
var treeData = [
  { "id" : "ajson1", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Simple root node", "date":"2018"},
  { "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root node 2", "date":"2018"},
  { "id" : "ajson3", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 1", "date":"12" },
  { "id" : "ajson4", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 2", "date":"12" },
  { "id" : "ajson5", "parent" : "ajson4", "text" : "File 1", "date":"12","children": false,"icon":"fa fa-file-o"  },
  { "id" : "ajson6", "parent" : "ajson4", "text" : "File 2", "date":"12","children": false,"icon":"fa fa-file-o"  }
];

var myTree = $('#using_json_2').jstree({ 'core' : {
  'data' : treeData // Use it here
}});

myTree.on('changed.jstree', function(e, data) {
  var selected = data.instance.get_selected(),
      // Get the path (array of IDs, since we pass true)
      path = data.instance.get_path(selected, null, true),
      // Use `map` to retrieve all nodes
      node_path = path.map(function(id) {
        return treeData.find(function(node) { return node.id === id; });
      });
  console.log(node_path);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>

<div id="using_json_2"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution , but i want to get all `json` rather than `[ "Root node 2","Child 2", "File 2"]` as shown in my `Expected Output` . please help me thanks in advance!!!